# A source of mesh (stl files) for testing a program that extracts properties from 3d solids?

Tags: mesh, trimesh

I'm writing a program in Python (using the Trimesh library) which will extract a number of geometric properties from solids which have been given to me as STL files.

I'd like to obtain some sample STL files which I can use for testing my system. I want really simple STL files: For example, if I had an STL file of a cube I could determine if the system is calculating volume correctly. If I had a simple STL for a Klien bottle I could verify that it understands that some objects have no volume but still have surface area.

There are a lot of "open-source" STL files downloadable from ThingVerse, but these files have been optimized for 3d printing, this a printable STL from ThingVerse will have different properties to an ideal version of that object.

I'm after the simple, ideal version. Does anybody know of a collection of such objects that I can use for testing?

If there's no such collection online, then I can probably make these shapes with SketchUp, 3DStudio or some CAD tool, but I was hoping to be able to reuse somebody else's work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Thingi10K dataset ( https://ten-thousand-models.appspot.com ); it is a large scale 3D dataset created to study the variety, complexity and quality of real-world 3D printing models.

In a nutshell, Thingi10K contains...

10,000 models
4,892 tags
2,011 things
1,083 designers
72 categories

50% non-solid
45% with self-intersections
31% with coplanar self-intersections
26% with multiple components
22% non-manifold
16% with degenerate faces
14% non-PWN
11% topologically open
10% non-oriented

There is also a simple query interface to search/explore/download the portion dataset based on contextual and geometric criteria (e.g. all the solid, non degenerate models).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any published collections, but [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/#download) is a free program which has the ability to generate some basic shapes (cone, sphere, tetrahedron, icosahedron, dodecahedron, etc.) very easily. Additionally, it can also compute geometric properties such as volume and area, so you could download "open-source" STL files and compute their correct properties in order to validate your code.